# update a field to other field in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table named Users.
I import some users from other table.
they have a parent_id

my table i now

```
id,parent_id,imported_rows_id

1,1,NULL ->my old data has not last row value

2,1,Null ->my old data has not last row value


3,1,1100

4,1100,1101

5,1100,1102

6,1102,1103
```

Now i want to change all parent_id to id where imported_rows_id = parent_id
same as here:

```
3,1,1100

4,3,1101

5,3,1102

6,5,1103

update users set parent_id  = (select id from users where parent_id=imported_rows_id)
```

Not allow on the same table

Sincerely

Comment: you have to alias the first table, in a join. Make sure you have an outer where clause before you blast over all your data by mistake

Comment: thanks for your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
update TableName t1 join
       TableName t2 on t1.imported_rows_id=t2.parent_id
set t2.parent_id=t1.id
where t2.imported_rows_id is not null
```

Result:

```
id  parent_id   imported_rows_id
--------------------------------
1   1           (null)
2   1           (null)
3   1           1100
4   3           1101
5   3           1102
6   5           1103
```

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ff1a/1)